# How do I show a list of internal contacts on a Sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

A Contact Details web part shows a single contact picked from the user list.

A Contacts List webpart is just a "dumb" list - i.e. every field needs to be manually filled, including email address, and I think is intended for external contacts.

Any suggestions how I would go about showing a list of internal contacts picked from the user list?

So far I've faked it by creating several Contact Details web parts, and hiding the chrome (title bar and border) for each, but it's rather slow and unwieldy and doesn't have any of the advantages of being a real list.

As it stands I don't have any tools other than out-of-the-box MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

### Site Users web part

This web part will show a list of one of:

- people and groups with direct permissions on the site
- people in the site's member group
- people in any named group

So I could create a new user group (with no specific permssions), add relevant users to it, and display that in a Site Users web part. However the out-of-the-box Site Users web part displays names (linked to profiles) but no other information, such as job title.

### Custom list

Or I could create a custom list with a column holding 'Person or Group' information, which can optionally be set to (a) limit selection to people only and/or (b) members of a particular group, and then display that list in a web part on the page.